# Map callouts showing incorrect images when map area changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Hi I am a little new with mapkit, I created a mapView where I show  annotations giving peoples locations along with name and photo. On each annotation there is a disclosure button that can be pressed to segue to that persons detail screen. As I am loading the people from an array I subclassed MKAnnotation and added an identifier property so that when the annotation is pressed I can identify the original array element and segue to the correct persons screen. There is an image of the person on the callout which also comes from the array via the identifier. This segueing works well, however I see that when I move the map around and then come back to the original location the peoples photographs are no longer in synch with the peoples names.
I am thinking that there is maybe an error in my viewForAnnotation method and would appreciate if anyone could point out what I am missing here.
Here is the methods code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // If it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // Handle any custom annotations.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tch4"];
            //pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 32);
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

            MyAnnotation *myAnn = (MyAnnotation *) annotation;
            // GET ARRAY IDENTIFIER
            identInt = [myAnn.identifier intValue];

            NSLog(@" Tag = %i", identInt);

            // Load and display photo using SDWEBImage
            UIImageView *photoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            NSString *urlPhotoId = [jsonTeach [identInt]valueForKeyPath:@"picture.id"];
            NSString *urlPhoto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://soon.nextdoorteacher.com/img/profiles/%@.jpg", urlPhotoId];

            [photoImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPhoto] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mortarboard2"]];

            photoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
            pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = photoImageView;

        } else {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

MyAnnotation is the subclass containing the identifer property
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the method, to check the view and add custom images and data onto the pin annotation view at the same time.